# Hiding vim command-line when it's not being used?

Tags: vim, vi

Is there any way to hide the vim command-line (ideally, automatically) when it's not being used? On small screens it takes up one valuable line. I'm thinking it would be 'normally' hidden, and appear when `:`, `/`, etc. are typed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`set cmdheight=0` achieves this functionality in Neovim from now on, thanks to [the efforts of developer Shougo Matsu and the Neovim maintainers](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1004)!

Comment: It does, and I'm using it, but worth pointing out this is only on NeoVim HEAD right now, not on a released version of NeoVim. Also, there are quite a number of [unresolved bugs](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/18961) with it. So probably not quite ready for prime time for most folks yet.

Comment: It's now available in nvim v0.8.0

Answer (score 13):

No, that is not possible. The command line is always present and there's no way to hide it without changing vim's sources.
It's not only used if you type `:` or `/` but also for status messages (try `ctrl-g`, for instance).

Comment: This is some truly abominable UI design. Neovim has an as-of-now [active issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1004) for this feature request.

Comment: ...and [here's the PR which fixes it](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/4382/) (needs a C writer to fix/finish it)

Comment: The PR has now been merged! That's right folks, *the default (Neo)vim user interface has just been improved*. Miracles can happen.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim with [patch 9.0.0114](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f39cfb72629f3e7fefaf578a3faa2619cd0654f8), `set cmdheight=0` hides the command line. This feature was removed in [9.0.0340](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/a2a8973e51a0052bb52e43a2b22e7ecdecc32003).

If you really need this feature, you can use Neovim 0.8.

Comment: `E487: Argument must be positive` this is `Vim 9.0.0809` so I guess not.

Comment: It was an experimental feature and support for it was abandoned.

Comment: @Heptite true, found it https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/a2a8973e51a0052bb52e43a2b22e7ecdecc32003

Comment: I updated my answer and mentioned that zero `cmdheight` was removed in 9.0.0340.

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier, you can do `set cmdheight=0` in neovim (`vim.opt.cmdheight=1` if you use lua). You'd still be able to interact with cmd input when you type ":".

The issue is that some messages might still be hidden, such is the case when recording a macro. For such events you'll need to add you own Callback.
This is the one I use to change `cmdheight` when a macro is being recorded:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "RecordingEnter" }, {
  callback = function()
               vim.opt.cmdheight = 1
             end,
})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "RecordingLeave" }, {
  callback = function()
               vim.opt.cmdheight = 0
             end,
})
```

or you can simply set a mapping to toggle it

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>sc",
               function()
                 vim.opt.cmdheight = 1 - vim.opt.cmdheight._value
               end,
              { desc = "Toggle cmdheight" }
)
```